# Google Maps' setOnPoiClickListener logs location of the tap instead of the POI

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, android-jetpack-compose

Using Google Maps API, I am trying to log the location of a Point of Interest from `setOnPoiClickListener`:

```
        setOnPoiClickListener { poi ->
            Toast.makeText(context, "Clicked: ${poi.name}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            Log.d("setOnPoiClickListener", "POI ${poi.name}, lat: ${poi.latLng.latitude}, lng: ${poi.latLng.longitude}")
        }
```

The google maps dependency:

```
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
```

However, the location logs I get show the location of the tap, not the POI. Meaning, every tap I make on the same POI results in different latitude and longitude.

The Google Maps Platform docs read: "When a user clicks (taps) on a POI, your app receives an OnPoiClick(PointOfInterest) event indicating the point of interest (POI) that the user clicked. The PointOfInterest **contains the latitude/longitude coordinates**, place ID and name **of the point of interest**." - [source](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/poi)

I would like to know what am I doing wrong and whether what I am trying to do is achievable (I assume it is). I understand this question might be simple for more experienced devs, but I just have nowhere to go for advice.

**Upd:**
For context, when I try to fetch the Place details via `FetchPlaceRequest` based on the POI's id, I get exactly what I need: the latlng represent the POI coordinates and not the tap coordinates. I am reluctant to use this method because it implies a short delay if the POI is tapped (a tap anywhere on the map other than POI gives latlng coordinates instantly):

```
fun fetchAndSelectPlace(placeId: String) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            try {
                val placeFields = listOf(Place.Field.ID, Place.Field.NAME, Place.Field.LAT_LNG)
                val request = FetchPlaceRequest.builder(placeId, placeFields).build()

                val placeResponse = placesClient.fetchPlace(request).await()
                _selectedPlace.postValue(placeResponse.place)
                Log.d("setOnPoiClickListener", "fetched latlng ${_selectedPlace.value?.latLng}")
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                Log.e("MapViewModel", "Error fetching place details", e)
                _selectedPlace.postValue(null)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks similar to this known issue in the Public Issue Tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/269765421 Feel free to star the issue for updates with regards to this.

Comment: Thank you @Yrll! I forgot about the Issue Tracker. Sadly no timeline for the resolution of this bug. I assume it should be an easy fix.